# Can Pareto Optimality be compared to Nash Equilibrium?

Tags: proof-techniques, game-theory

Given a state $s$, and a value function $v^i$ that determines the expected payoff for the i-th agent in that state, can the two definitions below, one of Nash equilibrium and another of Pareto optimality be compared to one another?

Nash equilibrium:
$$v^i(s, \pi^i_*, \pi^{-i}_*) \ge v^i(s, \pi^i, \pi^{-i}_*)\ \ \  \forall\ \  i \in \{1, 2, \cdots,N\}$$

Pareto optimality:
$$v^i(s, \Pi_\#) \gt v^i(s, \Pi)$$ for atleast 1 agent $i$,
and,

$$v^j(s, \Pi_\#) \ge v^j(s, \Pi)\ \ \  \forall\ \  j \in \{1, 2, \cdots,N\}$$

#### Notation Used

Nash Equlibrium = $(\pi^i_*, \pi^{-i}_*)$

Pareto Optimal stragey = $\Pi_\#$

Comment: I think your notation is somewhat confusing. What is $\Pi, \Pi_\ast, \Pi_\#$? That both concepts are not the same is easy to see, look e.g. at the Prisoner's Dilemma and find the Pareto-optimal point and the Nash equilibrium. However, you theoretical can compare optimal points and equilibria. There is still a lot of research going on that goes under the euphonic name "Price of Anarchy".

Comment: Hey, @ttnick I have updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: I understand the notation now, but what are you asking? I do not know what to add to my first comment unless, you have a more specific question.